# Which type of cache to use in Yii

Tags: mysql, caching, yii

We have a project that caches a search result that may vary between a few hundred kilobytes to up to 30-40MB. It is cached for 15 minutes and I wanted to ask for people's opinion on which type of cache that should be used for it. If storing it in MySQL database, it's table becomes huge - though that's not of much concern, the speed of caching here is more relevant. Would anyone suggest file based caching instead here, or should it remains DB bound?
While I understand it needs a few tests to figure it out, I wanted to ask if people here came across something like I'm describing here and can provide a suggestion.

Comment: Yii1 or Yi2 ?  please

Comment: We're using Yii1 for this